# Programming languages that compile into PHP?

Tags: php, compiler-construction, syntax

Beautiful syntax sugar helps in understanding a language.

Comment: Why would any sane programming language compile **into** PHP? That's like wanting to immigrate *into* Soviet Russia...

Comment: Are you serious!! That question does not make anysense??

Comment: @kerrek SB: In Soviet Russia, C++ compiles into PHP.

Comment: can you provide some insight into how we can understand YOUR language?

Comment: I just learnt some CoffeeScript. And I want to know if anyone had similar idea on PHP fo far.

Comment: I think this should be UP voted - kinda like a best of craigslist sort of thing - humor factor and all. :D

Comment: @jiyinyiyong: No such languages exist because PHP is not a good language to build off of or compile to.  Try Ruby.

Comment: @SLaks , I found https://code.google.com/p/php-snow/ on GogoleCode but still without a PHP generator.. I like Ruby, but Rails seems too complecated to me.

Comment: Considering the bad reputation PHP has, I'm surprised there isn't more interest in alternatives languages addressing its shortcomings while still running on the same platform and interoperating with the vast ammount of existing libraries. Similar questions for compilers targetting JavaScript, C++, etc, haven't been closed. It is as much a real question as those.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no serious meta languages atop PHP. The only useable language was [`pihipi`](http://www.google.com/search?q=pihipi).

Comment: thank you for your answer. But why do people don't like to talk about this?

Comment: @jiyinyiyong Though I can't speak for everyone, I doubt it's that anyone doesn't *want* to talk about it; it's that there's nothing to talk about. Client-side languages like Javascript tend to have more levels of abstraction developed (*jQuery, CoffeeScript*) because of the client-programmer base - often designers with little desire to get their hands dirty. PHP development doesn't support that sort of client-programmer base because it has little to do with aesthetic design and all to do with data management.

Comment: @Bracketworks , oh, bad PHP. Considering that plenty of people learn and use PHP, I was supposing there was something like PHP. So I found I was wrong.

Comment: There is one language called [snowscript](https://github.com/runekaagaard/snowscript) currently in development - it looks like the author has recently resumed development on it.

Comment: There is of course also [haXe](http://haxe.org/) which is by far the most established, complete and proven compile-to-php language. I don't know how I didn't think of that. It is the only compile-to-php language that has any real userbase, as far as I know - though I don't know how much of it's userbase actually targets php, since this meta-language has many other target languages.